# JUnit - How to test duplicate instruction in same method with different parameter?

Tags: java, junit, java-8, mockito, java-11

I have an update method but I'm having trouble doing the unit test. In the method, I need to validate if the object to be changed exists in the database and I also need to check if the new data that the user is inserting will not cause record duplication. For this, I do a search in the database at two different times using a `findById()`:

```
    public void update(Form form, Long storeCode, Long productCode, Long purchaseQuantity) {

    var id = new PrimaryKeyBuilder(DiscountPK.builder().build()).build(storeCode,productCode, purchaseQuantity);
    var targetToUpdate = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);

    var dataToInsert = SerializationUtils.clone(id);
    dataToInsert.setPurchaseQuantity(form.getPurchaseQuantity());

    var newPk = repository.findById(dataToInsert);
    throwExceptionIf(newPk.isPresent(), new DuplicatedPkException());

    targetToUpdate.getId().setPurchaseQuantity(form.getPurchaseQuantity());
    targetToUpdate.setDiscountPercentage(form.getDiscountPercentage());

    repository.save(targetToUpdate);

}
```

The problem is: I'm not able to differentiate these two `findById()` instructions in my unit test. Instead of passing it successfully, throws `NotFoundException` of my first validation. It is as if the first `given()` statement is being ignored and only the second statement is considered

```
    @Test
    public void update_successfully() {

        var targetToUpdate = ObjectFactory.createMain();
        var form = FormFactory.createUpdateForm();
        var id = ObjectFactory.createFirstAux();
        var dataToInsert = ObjectFactory.createSecondAux();

        given(repository.findById(id)).willReturn(Optional.of(targetToUpdate));
        given(repository.findById(dataToInsert)).willReturn(Optional.empty());

        given(repository.save(any())).willReturn(targetToUpdate);

        service.update(form, STORE_CODE, PRODUCT_CODE, PURCHASE_QUANTITY);
        verify(repository).save(targetToUpdate);
    }
```

Bonus code: Class that builds the object passed in `findById()`

```
 public class PrimaryKeyBuilder {

    private final DiscountPK id;

    public PrimaryKeyBuilder(DiscountPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public DiscountPK build(Long storeCode, Long productCode, Long purchaseQuantity) {

        id.setPurchaseBoxQuantity(purchaseBoxQuantity);
        id.setProduct(Product.builder().id(ProductPK
                .builder().productCode(productCode).store(Store.builder().code(storeCode).build()).build()).build());

        return id;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `Optional.of(accelerator)` returned when you change the `acceleratorRepository.findById(id)` part to match any argument instead? I suspect the matcher doesn't consider this `id` object same as whatever you pass in the `update` function.

Comment: Hello. The term "accelerator" was an error transcribing the code here. I adjusted. About your hypothesis, I also think that maybe the id that is passed in my test is considered different from what the Service class executes, even though the values are the same but the object itself is different (within service the id is constructed with a new )

Comment: Does the `DiscountPK` class define `equals` and `hashCode` methods?

Comment: Hello, @Tim Moore. There is no equals/hashcode in DiscountPK

Comment: For Mockito to detect that two different instances match, you'll need to define `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining mock behavior using `given` or `when`, you need to provide arguments that match the arguments that the code being tested will provide. The [Mockito documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers) explains: "Mockito verifies argument values in natural java style: by using an `equals()` method."

If the `DiscountPK` class does not override the `equals` method, the default implementation in `java.lang.Object` will be used. This compares object identity, and only returns `true` when both objects are the same instance.

The most straightforward solution, if you can modify the `DiscountPK` class, would be to override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in this class, to define equality based on the values it contains. Assuming that the `DiscountPK` class contains only two fields, named `purchaseBoxQuantity` and `product`, you could use the `java.util.Objects` class to define these this way:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        DiscountPK that = (DiscountPK) o;
        return Objects.equals(purchaseBoxQuantity, that.purchaseBoxQuantity) && product.equals(that.product);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(purchaseBoxQuantity, product);
    }
```

This also assumes that the `Product` class defines `equals` and `hashCode`.

Note that although Mockito only uses the `equals` method, and not `hashCode`, it is always recommended to override `hashCode` whenever overriding `equals`, to ensure that equal objects also have equal hash codes.

I would also recommend making the primary key classes immutable. This makes them easier to reason about, as the contents of an entity's primary key should never change. It also ensures that the return value of `hashCode` will not change over the lifetime of the object, which can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're mocking the repositories, then they won't actually save the changes when using `myRepo.save(myObj);`

You can use Mockito to simulate it, though: `when(X).thenReturn(Y)`.

e.g.,

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyServiceTest {
    
    @Mock private MyRepo myRepo;
    @InjectMocks private MyService myService;

    ...

    @Test
    void myTest() {
        MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
        Mockito.when(myRepo.findById(myObj.getId())
          .thenReturn(Optional.of(myObj));
        // perform desired test
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I changed given()...willReturn() to use when()...thenReturn() but the error continues

Comment: did you just change given()...willReturn() to when()...thenReturn() or did you add the imports and prepend Mockito to when()?

It needs to be ```Mockito.when(X).thenReturn(Y)```

Comment: I added the static import for Mockito but nothing changed, the error is the same as using given()... willReturn()